# Golang testing with dynamic linking for Kafka on M1 chip

Tags: go, testing, dynamic-linking

I'm trying to write some unit tests for a poc I'm doing in Golang / Kafka on a new M1 Mac.  I'm using the official Golang Kafka libs from confluent:

```
"github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka"
```

Apparently, this package has a dependency on a `librdkafka` which is not built for M1 (yet?).  For the build, there is a work around [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/issues/591#issuecomment-825048033), which goes something like this:

```
% brew install librdkafka openssl zstd
% PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib/pkgconfig"
% go build -tags dynamic *yadda yadda yadda*
```

This is fine for build/run.  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work for tests.  In the link describing the workaround, using `go test -tags dynamic ./...` seems  to work, but in my case the test run doesn't seem to read the exported PKG_CONFIG_PATH:

```
% go test -tags dynamic ./... -v
# pkg-config --cflags  -- rdkafka
Package libcrypto was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcrypto.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'libcrypto', required by 'rdkafka', not found
pkg-config: exit status 1
FAIL    smartAC/shared [build failed]
```

Even though that env var is set, at least in my shell:

```
% echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib/pkgconfig
```

Is there some trick to get go test tool to see the env var?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, never mind.  I sorted this...  in my ~/.zshrc I wasn't exporting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH, so I changed this:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib/pkgconfig"
```

to this:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Which seems to work.  Leaving the question up, just in case it might help some other noob like me :-).